# Different results on using OpenCV raw pointer and lambda for histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, lambda

Tried to rewrite the OpenCV code using lambda since they are really fast. But the results shows the histogram values not entirely the same, which affects the calculation afterwards.

Here are some of the logs I saw. I am expecting for the same color channel(r,g,b), their histogram value should be the same.

```cpp
hist b 255= 274163
hist2 b255= 271049
hist g 255= 260360
hist2 g255= 258447
hist r 255= 257104
hist2 r255= 255348
Elapsed time：136759us (136.759ms)
hist b 255= 274289
hist2 b255= 271266
hist g 255= 260346
hist2 g255= 258108
hist r 255= 257084
hist2 r255= 255236
Elapsed time：135269us (135.269ms)
hist b 255= 274294
hist2 b255= 271183
hist g 255= 260342
hist2 g255= 258242
hist r 255= 257099
hist2 r255= 255197
Elapsed time：142417us (142.417ms)
hist b 255= 274218
hist2 b255= 271021
hist g 255= 260375
hist2 g255= 258768
hist r 255= 257039
hist2 r255= 255643
Elapsed time：138296us (138.296ms)
```

Here is my code

```cpp
// use raw pointer access
std::vector<std::vector<int>> hists(3,std::vector<int>(256,0));
for (int y = 0; y < _opencvImage.rows; ++y)
{
    uchar *ptr = _opencvImage.ptr<uchar>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < _opencvImage.cols; ++x) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            hists[j][ptr[x * 3 + j]] += 1;
        }
    }
}

// use lambda
std::vector<std::vector<int>> hist_test(3,std::vector<int>(256,0));
_opencvImage.forEach<Pixel>(
[&hist_test] (Pixel &pixel, const int *pos) -> void {
            hist_test[0][pixel.x]++;
            hist_test[1][pixel.y]++;
            hist_test[2][pixel.z]++;
    }
);

printf("hist b 255= %d\r\n", hists[0][255]);
printf("hist2 b255= %d\r\n", hist_test[0][255]);
printf("hist g 255= %d\r\n", hists[1][255]);
printf("hist2 g255= %d\r\n", hist_test[1][255]);
printf("hist r 255= %d\r\n", hists[2][255]);
printf("hist2 r255= %d\r\n", hist_test[2][255]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing is a race condition, I simplified your example and I tried to understand what type you used for `Pixel`:

```
int main()
{
    using Pixel = cv::Point3_<uint8_t>;
    cv::Mat _opencvImage(120, 120, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> hist_test(3, std::vector<int>(256, 0));
    _opencvImage.forEach<Pixel>(
        [&hist_test](Pixel& pixel, const int* pos) -> void {
            hist_test[0][pixel.x]++;
            hist_test[1][pixel.y]++;
            hist_test[2][pixel.z]++;
        }
    );


    printf("hist2 b255= %d\r\n", hist_test[0][0]);
    printf("hist2 g255= %d\r\n", hist_test[1][0]);
    printf("hist2 r255= %d\r\n", hist_test[2][0]);
}
```

We know that the three values I print should be 120x120=14400, yet when you run the code you'll see, most likely, different values. This is due to a race condition because `forEach` according to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d)

> Invoke with arguments functor, and runs the functor over all matrix
>   element.
>
> The methods runs **operation in parallel**.

So when you have 2 threads looking a two pixels having the same value in one of the channels you have a race that generates undefined behavior corrupting your results.

To convince yourself (this is **not** the solution you should use) you can rewrite the program like this:

```
#include <mutex>
int main()
{
    using Pixel = cv::Point3_<uint8_t>;
    cv::Mat _opencvImage(120, 120, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> hist_test(3, std::vector<int>(256, 0));
    std::mutex mx;
    _opencvImage.forEach<Pixel>(
        [&hist_test, &mx](Pixel& pixel, const int* pos) -> void {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck{ mx };
            hist_test[0][pixel.x]++;
            hist_test[1][pixel.y]++;
            hist_test[2][pixel.z]++;
        }
    );


    printf("hist2 b255= %d\r\n", hist_test[0][0]);
    printf("hist2 g255= %d\r\n", hist_test[1][0]);
    printf("hist2 r255= %d\r\n", hist_test[2][0]);
}
```

Serializing the access to the histogram allows you to get the correct results, but obviously nullify the performance boost coming from using more threads.

Now, there are plenty of ways to obtain the performance you want, e.g. you can calculate histograms in disjoint areas in parallel and then sum them. But I would suggest to use the function [calcHist](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) of OpenCV that does exactly what you want and you can find an official tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html). I skimmed the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp) of `calcHist` I could see that `calcHist` leverages already acceleration (I can see calls to OpenVX and IPP implementations). So, I think it is unlikely that your code could perform better than the code shipped already with OpenCV unless you have a very peculiar use case and you are willing to invest a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and instant response! I figured this multi-thread thing out after I add another capture count pixel in lambda. After using ```calcHist``` as you recommended, my auto white balance runs much faster than before.